# MS Chart line draw issue

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I'm trying to draw a line between a clicked DataPoint and the Y-Axis. I'm adding a new series for drawing the line. My X-axis contains dates. The problem is when I add the series to chart, the x-axis becomes blank.

I didn't updated the X-axis by code. I tried to comment the RecalculateAxesScale() but of no use.

Here is my code:

```
            longTermSeries = new Series("Long Term");

            ChartArea area = chart.ChartAreas["draw"];

            area.RecalculateAxesScale();
            area.AxisX.Minimum = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Minimum;
            area.AxisX.Maximum = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Maximum;
            area.AxisY.Minimum = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Minimum;
            area.AxisY.Maximum = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Maximum;

            chart.Series.Add(longTermSeries);

            longTermSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            longTermSeries.Color = Color.Blue;

            longTermSeries.Points.Add(selectedDataPoint);
            longTermSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(area.AxisX.Maximum, selectedDataPoint.YValues[0]));
```

Comment: Does the problem happen when you add the new series? Or when you set the chart type, or start to add points?

Comment: I found my mistake. Actually I was manually showing month names instead of date on x-axis. That was causing the problem. Thanks for the reply